# Yahoo store editor can't link header variable with template.

Tags: yahoo

I know that this is not the right place to ask that sort of question, but it seems I can't find the answer anywhere. Basically I am stuck ! I am a complete novice with yahoo store editor, still I have to edit online store at store.yahoo.com using their build-in store editor. Some guy build the page and left no documents on how it works. So I am on my own now.

The page has one index and three sub categories. Each sub category has its' ID f.e. sub1, sub2 and sub3. The page uses "ey-master" template, which generates the template for each page. In the "Variable" menu page, I can edit **three** different header variables for index, sub2 and **both** sub1 and sub3. I've created new header variable for "sub3", edited it the way I want. However here comes the problem. I simply can't connect the variable to "sub3" ID. I don't know how. I checked the header part inside the "Template" section. I think the code bellow :

```
                 IF test @ey-redirect
                      then IF test EQUALS value1 @type
                                          value2 :main.
                              then TEXT @ey-main-header
                              else IF test OR 
                                            EQUALS value1 id
                                                   value2 :sub1
                                            EQUALS value1 ELEMENT position 0
                                                                  sequence path
                                                        value2 :sub1
                                          then TEXT @ey-main-header-1
                                          else TEXT @ey-main-header-2
                          else TEXT @ey-header
```

generates different headers based on ID ?! 
I'm not sure, but I hope, if I can manage to change the code to:

```
           IF test @ey-redirect
                  then IF test EQUALS value1 @type
                                      value2 :main.
                          then TEXT @ey-main-header
                          else IF test OR 
                                        EQUALS value1 id
                                               value2 :sub1
                                               value3 :sub3
                                        EQUALS value1 ELEMENT position 0
                                                              sequence path
                                                    value2 :sub1
                                                    value3 :sub3
                                      then TEXT @ey-main-header-1
                                      else TEXT @ey-main-header-2
                                      else TEXT @ey-main-header-3
                      else TEXT @ey-header
```

The Template will eventually "see" the header variable and work. However I have another problem as well. I checked the help available from yahoo online and how to use variables and "Edit" the template. Still I can't have active "Edit" button, once I'm inside the "Template" menu. In other words I can't edit the template. Next to that the "copy" button, doesn't behave the way it should be. Don't know why, probably it's my fault.... I think the version of the editor is 2.0, which I am not exactly sure.

I will appreciate any help suggested, because I have to make it work a.s.a.p. Thanks !

P.S. I know that I've made the mistake not to read all the information available, before I start, but I never thought it is that complex.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. I change the code above to

```
else IF test OR 
       EQUALS value1 id
              value2 :bellevue
       EQUALS value1 ELEMENT position 0
                     sequence path
              value2 :bellevue
then TEXT @ey-main-header-2
else IF test EQUALS value1 id
                    value2 :columbiacity
     then TEXT @ey-main-header-1
     else TEXT @ey-main-header-3
```

it works perfectly !

However there is a tip to it ! The template can't be easily changed. I had to add new variables to the template with "New" button and "replace" them in the code when needed.